# Create Color object from RGB values for API Level < Android 26 (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, colors, android-developer-api

I am working on an android project. I have RGB values of each pixel. I want to create a color object from it.

For android API level 26 and above, we can use Color.valueOf() method which will do the work for us. But it won't support API level below 26. Can someone help me with how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.  [Per the documentation, `Color` instances were introduced in Android O](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#color-instances), so they aren't available before then.  Note also that all of the instance methods on `Color` (such as `red()`, `green()`, `blue()`, etc.) are only available on API 26 and above - even if you were able to create an instance, you wouldn't be able to get any information out of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Color.argb(int, int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) which is available since API 1.

Sample usage:

```
Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0)
```

Which gives solid red color with no alpha. Hex representation: 0xFFFF0000

Comment: This returns an `int`, not a `Color` object.